# Integrating Normalize.css with the rails asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-reset

I followed the super simple direction on how to install the normalize-rails css reset gem outlined here
https://github.com/markmcconachie/normalize-rails

but I keep getting **error** stating that

```
"couldn't find file 'normalize-rails'"
```

when I included

`*= require normalize-rails`  in my **application.css** file. I ran `bundle`, `bundle update` etc, still no dice. Am I installing this incorrectly? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: just saying, you could download the normalize.css file and put it in vendor/assets/stylesheets

Comment: Did you add `*=require normalize-rails` before `*= require_tree .`? And what version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run the following command to see if the gem has been installed

```
bundle show normalize-rails
```

And remember to restart your server after installing new gem :)

Answer (score 4):

Check this Steps:

1. Add `gem 'normalize-rails'` in your Gemfile
2. Run `bundle install` command in your terminal
3. Check gem is installed or not by running `bundle show normalize-rails`
   in your terminal
4. restart your rails server
5. Add `*= require normalize-rails` in your **application.css** file before `*= require_tree .`

If you missed any steps then check it...

**NOTE:** You must using `Rails 3.1+`

Answer (score 0):

We also facing the same issue while upgrading the rails version.
solved using [this](https://rails-assets.org/#/components/normalize-css) reference.

instead using this  `//= require normalize-css` to `//= require normalize-css/normalize.scss`